# An Instagram post scheduling system w/ persistent, re-usable posts that supports batch scheduling

Tags: scheduling, social-networks, instagram

I'm looking for an Instagram media scheduling system (like HootSuite, Sprout, Buffer, Later CrowdFire etc. ) that would enable me to connect a new Instagram account and just 1-click reschedule hundreds of posts that were previously sent (with the same system) to another connected Instagram account prior. This in itself may require a certain set of conditions to be met, such as:

- the media to be kept by the app, ie. I won't be required to re-upload my photos
- the posts to be kept, ie. I won't be required to re-compose the post (select & arrange media, add description, select hashtags)
- the posts to be able to be batch-scheduled, ie. I select multiple (probably by checkmarks) and click 'schedule', which would add'em all to queue w/out me having to manually schedule each (queue can be manual or intelligent, that's of lesser importance here)
- the scheduled posts should be able to be displayed in a grid preferably and a post total cueue count would be appreciated so I know if all posts were able to 'migrate' to cueue
- the system has both a native mobile (iOS for me) and web desktop apps, preferrably
- the system uses own authentication (accounts), not only IG accounts
- the system supports Instagram business accounts (for the auto-posting API)
- the posts and assets don't get purged when an Instagram account gets disconnected (persistence)
  The point is to add resilience and function as a manually triggered Instagram account content re-creation in a case where an account may get disabled (or you want to migrate to another one).